# custom method in jquery

Tags: jquery

I got this code from Jquery in Action:

```
$.fn.photoslide = function(options) {
            var settings = $.extend({
                photoElement:'img.photoslidePhoto',
                transformer:function(name) {
                    return name.replace(/thumbnail/,'photo');
                },
                nextControl:null,
                previousControl:null,
                firstControl:null,
                lastControl:null,
                playControl:null,
                delay:3000
            },options||{});
$(settings.previousControl)
        .click(function() {
             showPhoto((settings.thumbnails$.length + settings.current - 1) 
                       % settings.thumbnails$.length);
                }); //Why not just use settings.current - 1??
```

the code is meant to be used with a slider. The slider has a button that displays the previous photo.
This is the code for the `showPhoto()` function:

```
function showPhoto(index) {
                $(settings.photoElement).attr('src',settings.transformer(settings.thumbnails$[index].src));
                settings.current = index;
            };

            settings.thumbnail$
                .each(function(n) {
                $(this).data('photo-index',n);
                })
                .click(function() {
                    showPhoto($(this).data('photo-index'));
                });
```

My question is, why can't the `index` argument for `showPhoto()` in the click event for `$(settings.previousControl)` be defined simply as `settings.current - 1`?

I know this is a long post, but I would appreciate it very much if someone could help me understand this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`settings.thumbnails$.length` is added to avoid negative indexes.

If it was not added and `settings.current` is `0`, the result would be `-1`. Important to know is that applying the modulus in JavaScript **does not make the number positive** (unlike in other languages like Python):

```
> -1 % 5
  -1
```

It would stay `-1` which eventually would result in an error if you try to access an array with it.

Adding `settings.thumbnails$.length` guarantees the number to be positive but does not change the result (as it is zero in the context of the modulus operator).

In case you wondered what the [modulus operator *<sup>[Wikipedia]</sup>*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) is for: I assume this is used to show the photos in a loop.

Comment: @Felix_Kling--but since `settings.thumbnail$.length` is one *more* than the number of elements, wouldn't adding it to `settings.current-1` just bring back the current slide?

Comment: @codeninja: `settings.thumbnail$.length` is not one more than the number of elements, that would not make sense. It tells you exactly how many elements are in the array. It is one more than the *highest index* because we start counting at `0`. Besides, `settings.thumbnail$.length % settings.thumbnail$.length` is `0`. So you effectively compute `0 + settings.current - 1 % settings.thumbnails$.length`, but, as said, by adding it, it is ensured that the result is positive.